# Can I separate$~\frac{dy}{dx}~$into$~dy,dx~$of$~\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{P\left(x,y\right)}{Q\left(x,y\right)}~$? so that I can compose a total DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6x-2y-3}{2x+2y-1}\tag{1}$$

$$P\left(x,y\right):=6x-2y-3$$

$$Q\left(x,y\right):=2x+2y-1$$

$$\therefore~~~\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{P\left(x,y\right)}{Q\left(x,y\right)}$$

$$Q\left(x,y\right)\frac{dy}{dx}=P\left(x,y\right)$$

Is the below operations allowed?

$$Q\left(x,y\right)dy=P\left(x,y\right)dx~~\leftarrow~~~\text{Seperated two operators}$$

As the above operation is allowed, then I can move the term of above RHS to the LHS and compose a total differential equation so that I can proceed solving DE as follows.

$$Q\left(x,y\right)dy-P\left(x,y\right)dx=0~~\leftarrow~~~\text{Total DE}$$

$$\left(2x+2y-1\right)dy-\left(6x-2y-3\right)dx=0$$

$$\underbrace{\left(-6x+2y+3\right)}_{=:P'}dx+\underbrace{\left(2x+2y-1\right)}_{=Q}dy=0$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(P'\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\left(-6x+2y+3\right)\right)=2$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(Q\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\left(2x+2y-1\right)\right)=2$$

Hence this total DE is an exact DE.

$$\int_{a}^{x}P'\left(s,y\right)\,ds+\int_{b}^{y}Q\left(a,t\right)\,dt=~\text{const}_{}\tag{2}$$

$$\left(a,b\right)~~\text{is a point where both functions are continuous.}$$

$~P',Q~$are both continuous on$~\left(0,0\right)~$

$$\therefore~~~\int_{0}^{x}\left(-6s+2y+3\right)\,ds+\int_{0}^{y}\left(2\cdot 0+2t-1\right)\,dt=~\text{const}_{1}$$

$$-6\int_{0}^{x}\left(s\right)\,ds+\int_{0}^{x}\left(2y+3\right)\,ds+\int_{0}^{y}\left(2t-1\right)\,dt=~\text{const}_{1}$$

$$-6\left(\frac{1}{2}s^{2}\right)\Big|_{0}^{x}+\left(2y+3\right)x+\left(t^{2}-t\right)\Big|_{0}^{y}=~\text{const}_{1}$$

$$-6\left(\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)+2xy+3x+y^{2}-y=~\text{const}_{1}$$

$$\underbrace{-3x^{2}+y^{2}+2xy+3x-y=~\text{const}_{1}}_{~\text{general solution}}$$

Comment: Yes, those operations are allowed. Maybe see [the wikipedia page on exact ODEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation) to start and then proceed to [differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function). I think the interpretation of these differentials and expressions of the form $Q dy - P dx$ requires some knowledge of differential geometry, though someone more qualified might be able to answer that.

Comment: I see. After gazed the book , I found the description which implies my that operation(separation) can be done. Should I delete my this post?

Comment: To be honest, I firstly want to memorize patterns for general solutions rather understanding theoretical things...

Answer (score -1):

Check coeff of x and y
6/2 is not equal to 2/2

so put x=X+h y=Y+k

now we get dY/dX and you'll get an equation from which separate h and k terms and constants in Numerator and Denominator.

Solve these linear equations in h and k in Nr and Dr by equating them to 0 and get h,k.remeber you have equated to 0 so no need to worry about these h and k terms at the moment. You are left with only X and Y terms.

now you get dY/dX equals a homogeneous DE solve it in variables X and Y and then put X=x-h and Y=y-k in the final answer.

Do keep (X,Y) and (x,y) in mind

P.S. I dont know how to write math equations here so wrote an explanation
Hope it helps. Thank you!!

Comment: Alternate method can be putting x=t+0.5 in this case. You will get the homogeneous DE directly this way in t and y. But the above method is universally applicable

Comment: Which line of equation are you talking of  "Check coeff of x and y 6/2 is not equal to 2/2"?

Comment: @electricalapprentice The original question itself
in numerator and denominator dy/dx=...
that is, eqn (1))

Comment: I see. I think that I've misread your that line.

Comment: ohh Np hope you got the root idea of the method and got your answer